# intersection multiplicity of plane curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C$ is a smooth cubic and $P=(0,0)$  an inflection point of  $C$, with tangent line $x=0$. The  degree 4 curves  $x^3y=0$ and $x^4=0$  intersect $C$ at $P$ with multiplicity $10$ and $12$, respectively. 
I´m struggling  with this: How to find a curve of degree $4$ intersecting $C$ at $P$ with multiplicity $11$? Does it exist? If it does, is there an obvious way to construct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you are asking, but here is my interpretation and answer. Let $C$ be a plane cubic and $E$ is a plane quartic then $C \cap E$ has 12 points counting with multiplicity. Is it possible that multiplicity of one of the points is 11 and then  multiplicity of the the remaining point is 1.

No, this is not possible. If there is such $E$ we get $D=11P+Q$ as the divisor on $C$ of intersection $C$ with $E$, and $Q \neq P$. Cubic is embedded into plane by the linear system $|3P|$, because $P$ is an infection point. On the plane $E \in |\mathcal{O}(4)|$, so intersecting $E$ with $C$ we get a divisor on $C$ linearly equivalent to $12P$. But $12P-D \sim P-Q$ is not a principal divisor on $C$ if $Q \neq P$. This follows from Abel's theorem.